# Selecting item from QGraphicsScene in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am loading image using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsSCene. I have multiple RectItems in QGraphicsScene. Code is given below;

```
def load_image(self,image_item):
    rect_list = [[20,30,70,35],[50,100,60,100],[410,450,60,100]]
    self.pic = QPixmap(str(image_item.text()))
    self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self.centralWidget)
    self.brush = QBrush(Qt.BDiagPattern)
    self.pen = QPen(Qt.red)
    self.pen.setWidth(2)
    self.load_view = self.scene.addItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.pic))
    for rect in rect_list:
        self.rect_item = self.scene.addRect(rect[0],rect[1],rect[2],rect[3],self.pen,self.brush) # x,y,w,h
        self.rect_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable) #Item is Selectable
        self.rect_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable) # Item is Movable

    self.gView.setScene(self.scene)
    self.gView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    self.gView.show()
```

Now, When ever I click on one rect_item from the item list in QgraphicsScene, I want to print that item.

[image: Screenshot is given here]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "print that item"? Print where/how?

Comment: When I click on any item, I want to print in the console that "Item Clicked!". That is enough for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the most simple solution, if you really need an "item clicked" message only, is to add Qt.ItemIsFocusable flag to the item and then use the focusItemChanged signal of the scene:

```
    def load_image(self, image_item):
        # ...
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self.centralWidget)
        self.scene.focusItemChanged.connect(self.focusChanged)
        # ...
        for rect in rect_list:
            self.rect_item = self.scene.addRect(rect[0],rect[1],rect[2],rect[3],self.pen,self.brush) # x,y,w,h
            self.rect_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
            self.rect_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            # required for focusItemChanged signal to work:
            self.rect_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsFocusable)

    def focusItemChanged(self, newItem, oldItem, reason):
        if newItem and reason == Qt.MouseFocusReason:
            print('item {} clicked!'.format(newItem))
```

This method has some issues, though, most importantly the fact that if an item is already selected (hence, it has focus) you won't get the signal.

There's no immediate solution for this, because basic QGraphicsItems are not QObject descendants, meaning that they cannot emit any signal.

If you don't need signal/slot support, you can subclass QGraphicsRectItem and reimplement its mousePressEvent:

```
class ClickableGraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, pen, brush):
        super(ClickableGraphicsRectItem, self).__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.setPen(pen)
        self.setBrush(brush)
        # flags can be set all at once using the "|" binary operator
        self.setFlags(self.ItemIsSelectable|self.ItemIsMovable)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(ClickableGraphicsRectItem, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print('item clicked!')

class MyProgram(QMainWindow):
    def load_image(self, image_item):
        # ...
        for rect in rect_list:
            self.rect_item = ClickableGraphicsRectItem(...)
```

If you *do* need some signal/slot mechanism, you could subclass the scene also and make the item emit its signal. This is not the *best* practice, but it works :-)

```
class ClickableGraphicsRectItem(QGraphicsRectItem):
    # ...
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(ClickableGraphicsRectItem, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.scene().itemClicked.emit(self)

class ItemClickableGraphicsScene(QGraphicsScene):
    itemClicked = pyqtSignal(QGraphicsItem)

class MyProgram(QMainWindow):
    def load_image(self, image_item):
        # ...
        self.scene = ItemClickableGraphicsScene(self.centralWidget)
        self.scene.itemClicked.connect(self.itemClicked)
        # ...
        for rect in rect_list:
            self.rect_item = ClickableGraphicsRectItem(...)

    def itemClicked(self, item):
        print('item {} clicked!'.format(item))
```

Alternatively, you can reimplement the mousePressEvent of the graphics view. In this example I just check if it's a QGraphicsRectItem (since you also have the QGraphicsPixmapItem), but if you add other item types you'll have to find a way to "recognize" them more carefully.

```
class ClickableItemView(QGraphicsView):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(ClickableItemView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            item = self.itemAt(event.pos())
            if isinstance(item, QGraphicsRectItem):
                print('item {} clicked!'.format(item))
```

Comment: @SravanJS You're welcome! Just out of curiosity, which approach did you use?

Comment: The first one! Actually I want to fetch data from a JSON file while clicking on an item. So instead of print, I put the body of json load. But I have to do more with the other approaches too. Thank you so much for the help.. :)

Comment: Now I have a challenge. When I click on a rect item, I want to print the coordinates of that rect item. Any idea?

Comment: Can't you just use [`scenePos`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#scenePos)?

Comment: When I am trying to fetch the value using the second last method, program is crashing. Crash is happening on "self.scene().itemClicked(self)" . It is not going after that.

self.rect_item =  ClickableGraphicsRectItem(rect[0],rect[1],rect[2],rect[3],self.pen,self.brush) 
self.rect_items = self.scene.addItem(self.rect_item)

This is how I done in the loading image function. Where I done wrong?

Comment: Change `itemClicked(self)` to `itemClicked.emit(self)`.

Comment: Now it's working! Thank you so much for using your time on this and helping :-)