# How to print data when a Selectable GraphicsItem is clicked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a JSON file which contains coordinate list and some other information.

My JSON structure look like this;

```
            "annotations": [
                {
                    "type": "Box",
                    "color": "red",
                    "box_top": 406.0,
                    "box_left": 656.0,
                    "box_height": 73.0,
                    "box_width": 40.0
                }
            ],

            "annotations": [
                {
                    "type": "Box",
                    "color": "green",
                    "box_top": 450.0,
                    "box_left": 700.0,
                    "box_height": 95.0,
                    "box_width": 47.0
                }
            ]
```

By taking the box values (box_top,box_left,box_height,box_width) I have drawn Rectangle using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene. The code is given below;

```
def load_image(self,image_item):
    self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self.centralWidget) # Created a QGraphicsScene
    self.pic = QPixmap(str(image_item.text())) # Loaded Image

    self.brush = QBrush()
    self.pen = QPen(Qt.red)
    self.pen.setWidth(2)
    self.pixItem = QGraphicsPixmapItem(self.pic)
    self.load_view = self.scene.addItem(self.pixItem) # Image Added to Scene

    # Opening JSON and fetching data
    # …
    for rect in json_file['annotations']:

        # Taken type and color and stored in variable

        self.box_type = rect['type']
        self.box_color = rect['color']

        # Taken box_top,box_left,box_height,box_width values

        self.rect_item = self.scene.addRect(rect['box_top'],rect['box_left'],rect['box_width'],rect['box_length'],self.pen,self.brush) # x,y,w,h
        self.rect_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable) #Item is Selectable
        #self.rect_item.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable) # Item is Movable

    self.fit_view = self.gView.setScene(self.scene)
    self.gView.fitInView(self.pixItem,Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
    self.gView.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
    self.gView.show()
```

Now What I want is when I click one box (say which has color red) from the GraphicsScene, I want to print its corresponding type and color. In a simple way, I want to print all data related to that box. A sample images also attached for reference. Note : Image is the output of this program.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code provided in the other [answer I gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58555164/selecting-item-from-qgraphicsscene-in-pyqt5/58572247?noredirect=1#comment104731507_58572247) (the second and last method are probably better) and get the data you need from the `item`. The "type" is the object class, the color is the [`pen()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractgraphicsshapeitem.html#pen) color.

Comment: I have gone through that code. Can you just clarify the argument of ClickableGraphicsRectItem which you mentioned in your answer? That is  "self.rect_item = ClickableGraphicsRectItem(...)". If I am calling only this with out "self.rect_item = self.scene.addRect(rect['box_top'],rect['box_left'],rect['box_width'],rect['box_length'],self.pen,self.brush)", I can not see any rectItem on Scene. Can you just help me with a sample code only for this part?I am new to PyQt5 so little confusion.

Comment: I cannot test it right now, and frankly I don't exactly recall what I did (that was a month and a half ago), but I'm pretty sure that I tested it using your data, and it worked (to be honest, you also said that it was working "fine"). If you have issues with *that* answer, please comment there, not here.